# if return type is list then how to return string in getmapping in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

```java
@GetMapping("/library/book/{genre}")
private List<Library> getBookByGenre(@PathVariable("genre") String genre) {
   if (libraryService.getBookByGenre(genre).isEmpty()) {
       return ;
   } else {
       return libraryService.getBookByGenre(genre);
   }
}
```

This is my controller code. When there is no data of the specific genre it returns an empty list but I want to return a string that shows "No data found for this genre" in postman.

```
"trace": "org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 : [{\"errorCode\":404,\"errorMessage\":\"No data found for this genre\"}]\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:113)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)\r\n\tat com.example.student.adapter.outbound.Repository.getBookbyGenre(Repository.java:64)\r\n\tat com.example.student.adapter.outbound.Repository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c14fd765.invoke(<generated>)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)\r\n\tat com.example.student.adapter.outbound.Repository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8c38c72.getBookbyGenre(<generated>)\r\n\tat com.example.student.core.service.StudentService.getBookbyGenre(StudentService.java:43)\r\n\tat com.example.student.adapter.inbound.StudentController.getBookbyGenre(StudentController.java:30)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\n",
    "message": "404 : [{\"errorCode\":404,\"errorMessage\":\"No data found for this genre\"}]",
    "path": "/Student/library/genre/lol"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to throw a custom exception:

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class NoBooksFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "No data found for this genre";

    public NoBooksFoundException() {
        super(ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/library/book/{genre}")
private List<Library> getBookByGenre(@PathVariable("genre") String genre) {
   if (libraryService.getBookByGenre(genre).isEmpty()) {
       throw NoBooksFoundException();
   } else {
       return libraryService.getBookByGenre(genre);
   }
}
```

And then you would have a global exception handler to deal with it:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {NoBooksFoundException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleCustomExceptions(Exception exception, WebRequest webRequest) {
        HttpStatus errorCode = this.resolveAnnotatedResponseStatus(exception);
        return this.handleExceptionInternal(exception, new ErrorInfo(errorCode.value(), exception.getMessage()), new HttpHeaders(), errorCode, webRequest);
    }

    private HttpStatus resolveAnnotatedResponseStatus(Exception exception) {
        ResponseStatus annotation = findMergedAnnotation(exception.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class);

        return Objects.nonNull(annotation) ? annotation.value() : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
}
```

Being `ErrorInfo` the following:

```java
public class ErrorInfo {
    private final int errorCode;
    private final String errorMessage;

    // getters, setters, constructor
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've edited the answer. Please check it.

Comment: When I am calling this Api from another project using resttemplate then again it is not working giving internal error in second project console it is showing error but working fine for first project. did you understand my doubt?

Comment: Ok, but that is a different thing. Please share the stack trace so that we can help you.

Comment: while sending trace limit reached for character , there is any other option to send trace to you?

Comment: Maybe adding it to your original question. I don't know how to start a chat.

Comment: I have added the postman trace in the question

Comment: It shows exactly the exception that you are throwing: `"org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 : [{\"errorCode\":404,\"errorMessage\":\"No data found for this genre\"}]\r\n\tat`. This is expected and is not an error.

Comment: but when i send the get request in postman then why it is also showing 500 along with that

Comment: Ok i will figure it out, Thanks for your help

Comment: Then, there must be more info in your logs regarding that 500. But the one you showed is the expected behaviour.